# SharedViewModel between fragment and its host activity by Koin

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, android-livedata

I want to achieve the communication between fragment and its host activity by using ViewModel(following: [Share data using a ViewModel](https://developer.android.com/guide/fragments/communicate#viewmodel)) to update the UI of activity when shared LiveData changed.

Start with declare ViewModel in the module

**MainModule.kt**

```
object MainModule {
    val module = module {
        viewModel {
            MainViewModel()
        }
    }
}
```

Then inject it to activity and fragment

**MainActivity.kt**

```
private val mainViewModel by viewModel<MainViewModel>()
```

**MainFragment.kt**

```
private val mainViewModel by sharedViewModel<MainViewModel>()
```

Observe the change of LiveData on activity

**MainActivity.kt**

```
mainViewModel.drawerState.observe(this, {
    // do something when it changed
})
```

Update the LiveData when the button(on fragment) clicked

**MainFragment.kt**

```
mainButton.setOnClickListener {
    mainViewModel.toggleDrawerState()
}
```

The LiveData declare in ViewModel

**MainViewModel.kt**

```
private val _drawerState = MutableLiveData<DrawerState>()
val drawerState: LiveData<DrawerState> = _drawerState

fun toggleDrawerState() {
    if (_drawerState.value == DrawerState.OPENED) {
        _drawerState.value = DrawerState.CLOSED
    } else {
        _drawerState.value = DrawerState.OPENED
    }
}
```

**DrawerState.kt**

```
enum class DrawerState {
    CLOSED, OPENED
}
```

**But It does not work as expected which means nothing happens when the button clicked**(can guarantee by debugging with breakpoint). I wondering to know where I've gone wrong or misunderstood. Thank you.

Comment: Is it the same when you do a postValue(DrawerState.CLOSED) instead on toggleDrawerState() ?

Comment: Wow, it's work now. Can you explain it to me a little more? Why it should use "postValue()" instead of "="?

Comment: I'm not sure since I don't know your entire scenario. Maybe, your toggleDrawerState() does something outside the main thread. To avoid this kind of issue, I tend to use postValue while handling livedatas.